# Create a restricted user on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, users

I need to grant guest SSH access to some user to review our server. He could:

- access only `/opt/www/` folder (and subfolders)
- can list folders
- but can't read files content
- can't edit/create files

How to do this properly?

Comment: Does it have to be SSH? Could you set up a read-only FTP server instead? Or just give them a dump of `/opt/www`'s contents? What you're describing *might* be possible with SSH, but it's certainly not the right tool for the job.

Comment: for example, an SSL and password-protected CGI script that does nothing but print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n" and then run `ls -lR /opt/www/` or `find /opt/www -ls`.  A slightly smarter version would either just exit if run more than once every 5 or 10 minutes, or cache a copy of the output for 5-10 minutes (or however long is useful) and `cat` that rather than re-run the `ls` or `find`.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you can't meet your requirements. The user is going to have to be able to read *some* files (the shell, `ls`, etc).

However, it seems to me you are massively overcomplicating this. If all you want them to do is to be able to review the directory structure, just give them a dump of `ls -lR`.